# Flex: Converting XML to ArrayCollection with more than one node

Tags: xml, apache-flex, arraycollection

I have an XML file I'm reading in where a branch of the tree looks like this:

```
    <data id="Shallow" label="Show Shallow Imagery (1 m)">
      <layer name="Bathymetry" url="OtherImagery" type="Dynamic" legendurl="">
        <visiblelayers>1</visiblelayers>
        <visiblelayers>4</visiblelayers>
      </layer>
      <layer name="Backscatter" url="OtherImagery" type="Dynamic" legendurl="">
        <visiblelayers>2</visiblelayers>
      </layer>
      <layer name="PCA" url="BUIS_Imagery" type="Dynamic" legendurl="">
        <visiblelayers>3</visiblelayers>
        <visiblelayers>4</visiblelayers>
      </layer>
    </data>
```

The user selects the layer using a radiobutton and in the click event, I pass layer.(@name==e.target.label).visiblelayers to a function that converts XML to an ArrayCollection.

```
 private function convertXMLtoArrayCollection(file:XMLList):ArrayCollection{
    var xml:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(file);
    var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder;
    var data:Object = decoder.decodeXML((xml));
    var array:Array = ArrayUtil.toArray(data);

    return new ArrayCollection(array);
}
```

For the "Backscatter" layer with only one visiblelayers node, I get the expected ArrayCollection returned.
[image]

But the other two layers returns an ArrayCollection with the visibleLayers node added in.
[image]

Why isn't it returning an ArrayCollection like this?
[image]

Comment: Did you step through the code and look at what "data" is? Did you review the decodeXML() method to see how it operates under the hood?

Comment: For Backscatter, data has a value of 2, and for the others, data is the visiblelayers array (the item below [0] in the second picture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the following function to return an ArrayCollection that was suitable for my code:

```
private function convertXMLtoArrayCollection1(file:XMLList):ArrayCollection
{
    var arrcol:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

    for each (var value:* in file)
    {
        arrcol.addItem(value)
    }

    return arrcol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Converting XML to ArrayCollection or Array in ActionScript Example please visit the following link there explain with example.

Converting XML to ArrayCollection or Array in ActionScript Example
http://javafws.blogspot.in/2013/12/xml-to-arraycollection-or-array-in.html